# How to make EFCodeFirst generate a column of type int for a property of type enum?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a model as follows:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public enum Sex { Male, Female }
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select either Female or Male.")]
        public Sex? Sex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I successfully generated a database using EFCodeFirst. Unfortunately, only `Id` and `Name` columns are created in the database and no `Sex` column is generated.

How to make EFCodeFirst generate a column of type int for a property of type  enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of EF CTP5, enums are still NOT supported. This is something that the EF team are working on though and we will likely get it on the RTM. For now you would have to use an `int?` for the `Sex` property.

EF Code First will ignore any property that is not a primitive type when creating a DB from your model.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple workaround you can use:

http://daniel.wertheim.se/2010/06/09/dealing-with-enumerations-and-entity-framework-4-code-first/

..but you might have to do a little refactoring once EF supports enums.